# Opaque struct versus class with private members

Tags: c++

It's common practice to use opaque structs in developing APIs to hide data from users (e.g., handles for resources). It is possible to realize such structs by declaring them in a header file and defining them in a `.cpp` file. My question is, why do we need such a pattern, while, we can simply use data encapsulation via OOP that `C++` offers? That is, if we need an opaque struct, why don't we simply define a class with private members?

Comment: The users of your structure need access to the header file. If the header file contains private members, the readers might infer implementation details. A fully opaque structure doesn't show *any* internal (`private`) members to readers of the header file. In C++ the most common way to do this is through the [pimpl idiom](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl).

Comment: AFAIK, opaque structs are use primarily in C APIs where things like `private` are not available. In C++, it's rather the Pimpl idiom to hide implementation details (though that's very similar if not the same). Even with making member variables private, it's not impossible to write (unsafe) code which manipulates the private members of class instances (by using type casts). Not that I would recommend this...

Comment: You were able to do this in Ada 83. But C++ never picked up on this great feature of Ada. But in C++ the class declaration needs to declare all private members. Essentially they're fixed for all time. That's not what you wanted the opaque handle for: you wanted it for _independence_.